# Show that Col(A)=Col(AB). A and B are square matrices of the same size, B is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I got one exercise that says $A$ and $B$ are both matrices of $n \times n$, $B$ is invertible, show that $Col(A) = Col(AB)$

I am a newb in Maths and here is what I come up with:

$$
\forall \vec x \in \Bbb R^n: A \vec x=\vec v\\
B \vec x=\vec u\\$$
Since B is invertible, its column vectors are linear independent and $\vec u=B\vec x$ spans $\Bbb R^n$, implies that $\vec u = \vec x$.

$\therefore  AB \vec x=A(B \vec x)=A\vec u=A\vec x$ then $Col(A) = Col(AB)$

However I am afraid I am wrong and this is not how one would write for proof. Any help on how to prove?

Comment: Your argument looks pretty solid to me...

Comment: So it's right? May I ask how would you prove if it were you?

Comment: Well, I usually prove set equality by element chasing, especially in an elementary setting. I would assume a vector is in $Col(A)$ and then show that it must also be in $Col(AB)$; then vice versa.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you're actually saying what you're trying to say with the math. For example, I don't know what to make of "$u=Bx$ spans $\Bbb R^n$, implies that $u=x$"; that just looks like word salad to me.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you are right. i just went to college for less than a year and i am not a good thinker in terms of math. sorry for the word salad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would write what you're going for:

Suppose that $v$ is in $col(AB)$. That is, there is some $x$ for which $v=ABx$. We find that if we set $y=Bx$, then $y$ is such that $Ay=v$. This means that $v$ is in $col(A)$.

Suppose on the other hand that $v$ is in $col(A)$. That is, there is some $y$ for which $v=Ay$. Because $B$ is invertible, we can find an $x$ for which $Bx=y$. However, that means that $v=ABx$, which is to say that $v$ is in $col(AB)$.

So, the two column spaces are the same, since they contain the same vectors.

Comment: that is very clear! thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would prove it looking at the associated linear maps:

Let $f$ the endomorphism of $K^n$ (I don't know what's your base field) with matrix $A$ in the canonical basis, $g$ the endomorphism with matrix $B$.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\col}{Col}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}\col A$ is simply $\im f$, ans 
$$\col(AB)=\im(f\circ g)=f\bigl(\im g\bigr)=f(K^n)=\im f=\col A$$
since, as $B$ is invertible, $g$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB=:C$. The rule
$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\>b_{kj}$
for multiplying matrices can be read as
$${\rm col\,}_j(C)=\sum_{k=1}^n b_{kj}{\rm col\,}_k(A)\in {\rm Col}(A)\qquad(1\leq j\leq n)\ .$$
This implies  ${\rm Col}(C)\subset {\rm Col}(A)$. As $B$ is invertible we  have $A=CB^{-1}$, and the same argument then proves ${\rm Col}(A)\subset {\rm Col}(C)$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

For col(A) to be equal to col(C). A has to be row equivalent to C, AB's columns are a lineair combination of the columns of A with weights from B. Since the columns of AB are lineair combinations of A, their column space has to be the same. This is because every vector of AB is in the column space of A. Also none of the non zero vectors are depicted on the null space because B is invertible so none of the columns of B are zero. Hence col(A) = col(AB).